# How to call https based api in one wso2 esb server from another wso2 esb server

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have created https based api in one of the wso2 esb 5.0.0 server, so now I want to call this https api from another wso2 esb 5.0.0.server. But I am getting SSL certificate error when calling https api from another wso2 esb server.

I have tried after importing localhost and wso2carbon certificates into client trust store and also wso2carbon key stores but no luck.

Does anyone tried ?

Comment: Which SSL error? Are you running with default keystores?

Comment: Unable to validate SSL certificate of "displaying the https api url in another esb server". Yes, I am running with default keystores